# Failed to create AVD from command line

Tags: android, linux, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to create an AVD on a linux virtual machine from command line using:

android create avd --force -n ANDROID_1.6_TEST -t android-16 -c 1000M

and getting error:
Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.

this command worked for me on windows. plus i have the sdk. and i found android-16 after running:
android list target

how can i fix this?

i also tried:
android create avd --force -n ANDROID_1.6_TEST -t android-16 -c 1000M --abi armeabi-v7a
and got:
Error: Invalid --abi armeabi-v7a for the selected target.

what exactly is the abi and how do i solve my problem? i just want to create an avd for Android 4.1.2

thanks